# Nuxtjs and Sanity CMS - $sanity.fetch() returns null on page change in asyncData

Tags: nuxt.js, sanity, asyncdata

I'm using NuxtJS with Sanity CMS.

I've setup a few page components, of which each page component is using the asyncData hook to fetch data from the CMS to display the page.

My page components all mostly look like this, but with different `groq` queries:

```html
<script>
import { groq } from '@nuxtjs/sanity';

export default {
    async asyncData({ $sanity }) {
        const query = groq`
            *[_type == "about"][0]
        `;
        const about = await $sanity.fetch(query);
        console.log(about); //returns proper data on page load, returns null on page change
        return { about };
    }
};
</script>
```

On initial page load or entire page refresh, the page loads just fine - for all pages in my app.

When using the local dev server, when I change pages using a `<NuxtLink>`, every page that follows this pattern fails to return data with the `$sanity.fetch()` method.  Every time it returns `null`.  This makes it really difficult for me to develop page transitions.

I can try to convert these to use the `fetch` hook, but AFAIK, this is the right use-case for `asyncData`.

In terms of versioning, here is what's in my package.json

```json
{
    //...,
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/sanity": "^0.9.4",
        "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.0",
        "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.1.12",
        "@sanity/asset-utils": "^1.1.5",
        "@sanity/client": "^2.13.0",
        "@sanity/image-url": "^0.140.22",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "core-js": "^3.15.1",
        "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
        "nuxt-gsap-module": "^1.3.2",
        "vue-youtube": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.1",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
        "eslint": "^7.29.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.12.1",
        "fibers": "^5.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.3.2",
        "sass": "^1.35.2",
        "sass-loader": "^10.2.0"
    }
}
```

In terms of my nuxt config, here it is:

```js
export default {
    // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
    target: 'static',

    // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
    head: {
        titleTemplate: '%s - My great project',
        title: 'My Project',
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: 'en'
        },
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
            { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
        ],
        link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
    },

    // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
    css: ['@/styles/main.scss'],

    // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/sanity-image-builder.js' },
        { src: '~/plugins/sanity-asset-url.js' },
        { src: '~/plugins/youtube.js', ssr: false }
    ],

    // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
    components: true,

    // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    buildModules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
        '@nuxtjs/sanity/module',
        '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
        'nuxt-gsap-module'
    ],

    // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/svg'],

    // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
    build: {
        loaders: {
            scss: { sourceMap: false },
            sass: { sourceMap: false }
        }
    },

    generate: {
        fallback: true
    },

    // Override santity config here.
    privateRuntimeConfig: {
        sanity: {
            token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN
        }
    },

    styleResources: {
        scss: ['./styles/*.scss']
    }
};
```

Comment: If you stay on your component's page and hit refresh, `asyncData` should not be triggered. `asyncData` should only be working when `nuxt-link`-ing to some routes. Then, I don't really see a lot of issues with `fetch()` and I (personally) find it superior most of the time. Can you make a `console.log` just before `const query = groq` just to be sure when this hook is run in your app?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when i stay on the page and hit refresh, `asyncData` is triggered.  I added a console.log() where requested, and this hook is being hit in the following scenarios:

* on load of my application.
* on page refresh of a page component
* on linking to a page component with <NuxtLink>

Comment: Strange that `asyncData` works in this context. Should not. Maybe a middleware or a redirect of some sort? You're maybe using `target: server` (default)? Not sure if this can have an impact.

Comment: Thanks.  Weirdly, adjusting this to fetch() did not solve the issue.  Seems to be something odd with $sanity.fetch(), where it's returning null on the client side.  If i console.log() its result, i can see on the server-side, it logs the data, but on client side it return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do use `privateRuntimeConfig`, your env variable will only be available on SSR. Hence the first time you do reach the page, you do have access for it.

Then, when you navigate (client-side only so), you do not have access to it anymore on your client. As explained in the [official documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-runtime-config).

[Sanity's documentation](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/configuration#runtime-configuration) is talking about the `privateRuntimeConfig`, meanwhile I do wonder if their token is aimed only for SSR or not. Usually, you do have a public token that you can expose through the `publicRuntimeConfig` key.

There is a `headless` channel on Discord that is available here: https://discord.gg/H4hJBMCK
Otherwise, posting [a Github issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sanity-module/issues/new/choose) will probably lead you to an answer from Daniel.

But it is possible that Sanity is aimed at fetching the content on server only, not sure.

There is a [setToken](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/usage/#settoken) method but it this one is aimed at using `req` only, it means that this is not suited towards a `target: static` build?

---

EDIT: nvm `Ovi` achieved to make it work as shown here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/sanity-module/issues/99#issuecomment-813993013
This one should probably work!

PS: was kinda writing as I was looking into the issues. Sorry if it's a bit messy. Tell me if the latest solution works and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This was the issue exactly!  The `withCredentials: true` fixed the problem for me.  Thanks so much :)